# Linq to SQL search for wildcard in double

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, double, contains

In a Linq to SQL I am trying to search for a value of the type double:

```
var q = from a in db.GetTable<HKKS_Medlemmer>()
            from g in db.HKKS_Get_grader_Kun_Grad(Convert.ToInt32(a.Skif))
            where a.Aktiv == true &&
             (a.Skif.ToString().StartsWith(SearchValue) ||
             SqlMethods.Like(a.Navn, "%" + SearchValue + "%") ||
              SqlMethods.Like(a.Mellemnavn, "%" + SearchValue + "%") ||
              SqlMethods.Like(a.Efternavn, "%" + SearchValue + "%") ||
              SqlMethods.Like(a.Adresse, "%" + SearchValue + "%") ||
              SqlMethods.Like(a.Telefon, "%" + SearchValue + "%") ||
              SqlMethods.Like(a.Mobil, "%" + SearchValue + "%") ||
              SqlMethods.Like(a.PostNr, "%" + SearchValue + "%") ||
              SqlMethods.Like(a.town, "%" + SearchValue + "%") ||
              SqlMethods.Like(a.mail, "%" + SearchValue + "%"))
            orderby a.Navn
select new
            {
                Grad = g.Grad,
                Skif = a.Skif,
                Navn = a.Navn,
                Mellemnavn = a.Mellemnavn,
                Efternavn = a.Efternavn,
                Adresse = a.Adresse,
                Telefon = a.Telefon,
                Mobil = a.Mobil,
                PostNr = a.PostNr,
                town = a.town,
                mail = a.mail,
                Picture = "http://www.hkks.dk/" + a.Picture,
                Age = db.fn_GetAge((a.CPR), DateTime.Now),
                Cpr = a.CPR

            };
```

I have also tried this:

```
var u = from a in db.GetTable<HKKS_Medlemmer>()
                from g in db.HKKS_Get_grader_Kun_Grad(Convert.ToInt32(a.Skif))
                .Where  (p => Object.Equals(a.Skif, SearchValue))
                orderby a.Navn
                select new
                {
                    Grad = g.Grad,
                    Skif = a.Skif,
                    Navn = a.Navn,
                    Mellemnavn = a.Mellemnavn,
                    Efternavn = a.Efternavn,
                    Adresse = a.Adresse,
                    Telefon = a.Telefon,
                    Mobil = a.Mobil,
                    PostNr = a.PostNr,
                    town = a.town,
                    mail = a.mail,
                    Picture = "http://www.hkks.dk/" + a.Picture,
                    Age = db.fn_GetAge((a.CPR), DateTime.Now),
                    Cpr = a.CPR

                };
```

But none of them is giving me the correct result, if i am searching for 994 and expecting the result to give me the record of 99469.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which field is the double? Can't you just convert it to a string first and then do a `LIKE` on it?

Comment: a.Skif is the double. The .StartsWith actually generate a LIKE [994%], but the convert ToString() generate a (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), [t0].[Skif], 2) LIKE @p11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment that the `.StartsWith` method generates the following SQL:

```
(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), [t0].[Skif], 2) LIKE @p11)
```

you can use the following SQL to illustrate the problem:

```
DECLARE @val AS FLOAT
SET @val = 99469
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), @val, 2)
```

If you run that SQL, you'll see the output is a string that most definitely does not start with "994":

```
9.946900000000000e+004
```

In order to convert 99469 to a string without using the `e+` notation, you can rewrite the statement like this:

```
Convert.ToInt32(a.Skif).ToString().StartsWith(SearchValue)
```

That will generate the following SQL, which should solve the problem:

```
WHERE (CONVERT(NVarChar,CONVERT(Int,[t0].[Skif]))) LIKE @p11
```

It would be nice if you could just declare something like this:

```
a.Skif.ToString("####").StartsWith(SearchValue)
```

but the `.ToString()` method doesn't support that in LINQ to SQL (I got a `Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.` error message when I tried).

Also, there may be other workarounds. With EF4 there may be something in `SqlFunctions` that allows you to do the conversion in one step, without converting to an `INT` (or a `BIGINT`, if necessary). Really, all LINQ to SQL needs to do is generate the statement with a 0 as the last parameter, instead of a 2 (i.e., `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), @val, 0)`).

Hope that helps.